# Objective-C Preprocessor Definition, Dynamic C-String to NSString Declaration

Tags: c++, objective-c, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to create a macro definition that can emit C++ or Objective-C depending on context but can't seem to construct an NSString inside a macro easily. The C++ version is simple because it uses regular strings, but making one that emits NSString is proving tricky:

```
#define FOO(x) bar(@##x)
```

The intended result is to convert a string argument to an NSString argument by prefixing with `@`:

```
FOO("x")
// => bar(@"x")
```

What I get instead is an error that prevents compilation:

```
Pasting formed '@"x"', an invalid preprocessing token
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSString *x = @"text";
```

Equals:

```
NSString *x = CFSTR("text");
```

PS NSString* and CFStringRef and __CFString* and also NSCFStringRef are all the same: [Toll-Free Bridged Types](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html)

Comment: `CFSTR` is promising but it's a `CFStringRef` and not an `NSString*`.

Comment: @tadman they are one and the same, and are toll-free-bridged.

Comment: I'm getting "Incompatible pointer types passing 'CFStringRef' (aka `const struct __CFString *`) to parameter of type `NSString*`" when trying this.

Comment: @tadman You can cast `CFSTR` to `NSString*`, it's [toll-free bridged](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010677).

Comment: The definition that worked: `#define AS_NSSTRING(x) ((NSString*)CFSTR(x))`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `##` to concatenate elements unless they form a valid preprocessing token together, but you can call `NSString`'s constructor that takes a C string, like this:

```
#define FOO(x) [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(x)]
```

Comment: Is that going to be something that has to be de-allocated later, unlike `@"..."` is static, right?

Comment: @tadman This produces an autoreleased string, you do not own it unless you retain it.

Comment: Should be `stringWithUTF8String:`, instead.

Answer (score 3):

Um, why not this:

```
#define FOO(x) bar(@x)
```

?

There's no need to do token pasting or stringifying or anything weird. You just want what's in the argument list at the substitution point to be preceded by an @ sign. So just do that.

Comment: only works if x is in quotes.  Sometimes that is not desirable.  For example: `#define CASE_TO_NAME(x) case x: return (NSString*) CFSTR(x); break` then a switch statement `switch (val) { CASE_TO_NAME(foo); CASE_TO_NAME(bar); // etc. }`

Comment: Sure, but that's not what the question was about. And your example will break because it doesn't stringify `x` in `CFSTR(x)`.

Comment: My example is fixed when you change to `CFSTR(#x)`, which should be obvious.  (Why can't I edit my comment?!)